# Orthogonal Transformation Matrices issue

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm really confused. If $V$ is an orthogonal matrix that transforms matrix $U_1$ into matrix $U_2$ why is it that $U_2 = V^TU_1V$?

With what I know, an orthogonal matrix is one such that $V^{-1} = V^T$:

Thus if $U_2 = VU_1$ then I cannot perceive how $U_2 = V^TU_1V$

Comment: You need to check, wherever you were reading that, what do they mean by 'transforms'? When $U_1$ is used to define a linear transformation $y=U_1x$, then changing variables in both the domain and codomain according to $V$, means $y=Vy'$ and $x=Vx'$. This means that the linear transformation becomes $Vy'=U_1Vx'$, or in other words $y'=V^{-1}U_1Vx'=V^TU_1Vx'$.

Comment: I'm looking at transformation matrices for Euler angles. In my notes it states "The transformation from $U_1$ to $U_2$ is an orthogonal transformation. Let $V$ be the transformation matrix: so we have $U_2 = V^T U_1 V$  "

Comment: Looks like a change of basis transformation which are typically of this form. An orthogonal change of basis matrix has the advantage of being an isometry so that lengths are preserved.